# How to check for NULL in MySqlDataReader by the column's name?

Tags: c#, mysql, null, dbnull, mysqldatareader

How can I check for a `NULL` value in an open `MySqlDataReader`?

The following doesn't work; it's always hitting the `else`:

```
if (rdr.GetString("timeOut") == null)
{
    queryResult.Egresstime = "Logged in";
}
else
{
    queryResult.Egresstime = rdr.GetString("timeOut");
}
```

`rdr.IsDbNull(int i)` only accepts a column number, not name.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var ordinal = rdr.GetOrdinal("timeOut");
if(rdr.IsDBNull(ordinal)) {
  queryResult.Egresstime = "Logged in";
} else {
  queryResult.Egresstime = rdr.GetString(ordinal);
}//if
```

or

```
if(Convert.IsDBNull(rdr["timeOut"])) {
  queryResult.Egresstime = "Logged in";
} else {
  queryResult.Egresstime = rdr.GetString("timeOut");
}//if
```

Comment: You are the Winner 0f your very own green check.  I used the second one.  Thanks!

Comment: small typo in the in second example: change "IsDbNull" to "IsDBNull"

Comment: This is crazy long for a null check.

Answer (score 14):

<strike>if(rdr.GetString("timeOut") == DBNull.Value)</strike>

`null` is not the same as `DBNull`

I am sorry, wrong answer, Sam B is right. I mistook this for `DataRow` stuff.

SqlDataReader does have strongly typed `GetString()` and provides `IsDBNull(int column)` for this case.

Comment: I think it should be `DBNull.Value`

Comment: Heres what I get Error 1:Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'

Answer (score 4):

You must call `rdr.IsDBNull(column)` to determine if the value is `DbNull`.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the object that retrive from NULL field with [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Change `null` to `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Heres what I get Error 1:Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull' –

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

`If (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rdr.GetString("timeOut"))`

Comment: Has the same effect as (rdr.GetString("timeOut") == null)

Comment: @rd42: so what is the actual value in that field when you debug? just curious?

Comment: The value is:  12/7/2010 10:16:46 AM  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one I like:

```
var MyString = rdr["column"] is DBNull ? "It's null!" : rdr.GetString("column");
```

**E.g.** (for the original requirement):

```
queryResult.Egresstime = rdr["timeOut"] is DBNull ? "Logged in" : rdr.GetString("timeOut");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private T GetNullableValue<T>(MySqlDataReader rdr, string parameterName)
    {
        object value = rdr[parameterName];
        if (value is DBNull)
            return default;

        return (T)value;
    }
```

And the usage for example:

```
string message = GetNullableValue<string>(rdr, "Message");
bool flag = GetNullableValue<bool>(rdr, "Flag");
DateTime startTime = GetNullableValue<DateTime>(rdr, "StartTime");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that I created to read `DBNull` and return a `default(T)` incase:

```
   private T GetNullable<T>(MySqlDataReader reader, int ordinal, Func<int, T> getValue)
        {
            if (reader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            return getValue(ordinal);
        }
```

It can be used like this:

```
   if (reader.Read())
            {
                account = new Account();
                account.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                account.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                account.MailVerifiedAt = GetNullable(reader, 2, reader.GetDateTime);
                account.MailToken = GetNullable(reader, 3, reader.GetString);
            }
```

The generic type `T` will be resolved based on the return value of the `reader.`- method. If it returns a string you will receive a `null` incase of `DBNull`. If it is an `int` it will return `0`, etc.

Note: for integer values it might not be desired to get a `0` so be careful.