# How to convert mySQL NULL value to integer 0 in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am reading data from MySQL in C#. 
If the *reader["A"].ToString* is a **NULL** value in the MySQL table, I want the following command: 
**int A = 0**. 
Else (if *reader["A"].ToString* is not NULL), **int A = 1**.

How can I do this? I tried `if(Convert.IsDbNull(reader["A"]))` but my C# Express isn't recognising *IsDbNULL*.

(I am able to get normal Varchar or Int data from the table)

Comment: It is `Convert.IsDBNull`, with an upper case `B`

Comment: do it in the query directly? `select coalesce(field_with_null`, 0)`

Comment: @Habib, thank you! Please send your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Sorry for the inattention, I found the wrong code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739641/how-to-check-for-null-in-mysqldatareader-by-the-columns-name

Comment: @drspuv, thanks, but this is a typo, and there is a close reason for that, I have already voted to close this question.

Comment: side note -> use the ternary operator here.  `int A = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["A"]) ? 0 : 1`

Comment: Thank you @Jonesy, we learn something every day!

Answer (score 0):

As @Habib corrected the typo, there is the code for the question if anybody would need it:

```
if (Convert.IsDBNull(reader[A])) A = 0;
else A = 1;
```

Thank you @Jonesy for upgrading the code:

```
int A = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["A"]) ? 0 : 1
```